# разметка диска debian linux

Tags: linux, debian

мне нужно установить debian
мне нужен диск на котором будут мои файлы музыка картинки и прочие документы
и собственно диск на который установится ос debian

озу 8гб

мне нужна помощь. как правильно разметить диск?

в винде просто С для ос. Д для всего всего остального.

может кто выложить скриншоты правильной разметки в моем случае?

Comment: простите, «скриншоты» чего именно вы хотели бы увидеть?

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, скриншот разметки. перед установкой ОС. нужно сделать разметку диска. мне нужен один раздел(диск) где будет у меня файлы музыка картины и прочие документы. и собственно диск куда установится ОС debian. в windows просто С обычно операционная. D обычно идет диск под файлы картинки фильмы.

Comment: https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/apc.html.ru

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев, мне это не подойдет

Comment: ну вот вам скриншот реальной разбивки одного блочного устройства на два: http://paste.debian.net/1128647/ . второе примонтировано в каталог `/d0`

Answer (score 1):

В случае UEFI системы:

1. Размер: 100 mb; ФС: Fat32; Флаги: ESP, Boot; Точка монтирования: /boot/efi
2. Размер: 50  Gb; ФС:  Ext4; Точка монтирования: /
3. Размер: всё что осталось; ФС: Ext4; Точка монтирования /home